# E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:351 failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE: no CUDA-capable device is detected

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I have installed GTX 1660 Super Card. Then installed CUDA 10.1 with cudnn 7.6.4.38
And when I run following code `import tensorflow as tf
import os
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI bus 1"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "1"

a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
c = tf.matmul(a, b)

print(c)`

I get the following error
2020-04-28 19:59:34.933933: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:351] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE: no CUDA-capable device is detected

I tried changing the code as follows but did not work

```
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0"
```

also tried

`os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "2"`

Comment: `CUDA 10.1 (10.1.105)` support `>= 418.39` Nvidia driver. Check your 
 Nvidia driver version. Try to match the requirement. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For finding the compatible versions of CUDA, Tensorflow, Python, cuDNN, you can visit the official site: [www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu).
Please check, if you have the right versions.

(off topic) In case you are also using Docker containers:
I would recommend an image like this: [nvidia/cuda:10.1-cudnn7-devel-ubuntu16.04](https://hub.docker.com/layers/nvidia/cuda/10.1-cudnn7-devel-ubuntu16.04/images/sha256-b6dca2906018abe9d3d8ea9effb10c9a71b07391c190d7624e4174024c528a31?context=explore)

Where:

- CUDA_VERSION=10.1.243
- CUDNN_VERSION=7.6.5.32

Also make sure you have compatible versions of tf, python:

- Tensorflow-2.2.0 or 2.3.0
- Python 3.5-3.8

Next thing to is to make sure your GPU driver is up to date, or update it accordingly.